# Retrieve String from `.dataTaskPublisher`

Tags: ios, json, swift, combine, urlsession

I am trying to return just a string from my node.js Express server. It's a basic server that returns "hello, world!" but not as a `JSON` object but as a regular string. Here is my code from my request.

```
URLSession
    .shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode(type: String.self, decoder: decoder)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

I think I'm doing it right but I get this but when I run it, I get this error: `The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.`

**Update**

So, as per the comments, I am not returning `JSON` so I can't use the `JSONDecoder`. That said, I wanted to use this in a generic fashion and some APIs will return `JSON` some will return `String`s and some will return `Int`s and some will return `Array<Codable>`. Is there a way to use combine to try and get these values back from my various API endpoints?

I know that I can do something like this:

```
URLSession
    .shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .map(\.data)
    .compactMap { String(data: $0, encoding:. utf8) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

but I want to be able to call each of my endpoints with this function. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is `decoder`? A `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: What's this?  .decode(type: String.self, decoder: decoder)

Comment: Where in the World is Carmen Sandiego?  Where in the world is your data model?

Comment: If it's returned *not as a JSON object* why do you decode it? And rather than `error.localizedDescription` read just the `error`. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @El Tomato, I remember playing that game in the late 80's, it was great.

Comment: @Sweeper, a `decoder` is a `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: @Sweeper, what can I do to get the downvote removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a decoder, just convert data to string using a String initializer.

```
var cancels: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

func fetchData() {

    URLSession
        .shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map(\.data)
        .compactMap { String(data: $0, encoding:. utf8) }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink (
            receiveCompletion: {
                print("Completion: \($0)")
            },
            receiveValue: { result in
                print("String: \(result)")
            })
        .store(in: &cancels)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am looking for a way to do it using the `.decode` method.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the `decode` method?

Comment: Your dataTaskPublisher isn't returning JSON, so you can't use a JSONDecoder on it.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielT.  LOL, I was just super panicked and was telling myself `compactMap`ing the `String` was leaving a hole for side cases to creep through but I can actually treat the data as `JSON` first, if this fails then I can try `UTF-8` and so on. Does anybody think that's a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

I personally gave up on having a single publisher chain, and I had two calls for HTML and the other for model data. But then I found sharedPublisher examples. Although I stuck with the two call approach instead of this, at least its food for thought. I personally would only call Data calls for models in 1 case and HTML requests from webpages in another where the callHTML can be used...

Shared publisher lets you break off after the .dataTaskPublisher(for:url)

```
let sharedPublisher = urlSession
                      .dataTaskPublisher(for:url)
                      .share()

cancellable1 = sharedPublisher
                .tryMap() {return $0.data}
                .decode(type: T.self, JSONDecoder())
                .recieve(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: {}, receiveValue: {}

cancellable2 = sharedPublisher
                .map() { $0.response }
                .sink( receiveCompletion: {},
                       receiveValue: { response in print("html") } )
```